# VirtualBox is using more processors than allotted

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu

I have a VirtualBox Windows VM configured to use 3 out of 4 processors (see screenshot), but when my computer froze (see description below) recently, I used `top` and discovered that the VirtualBox process was using 400% of my CPU.

Doesn't that mean that it took all 4 of my processors? How is this possible? How can I prevent VirtualBox from taking all my CPU?

[image: virtual box processor tab]

[image: hardware acceleration]

**EDIT**

By 'froze', I mean  it became almost non-responsive. I could get the cursor to move at a great delay (read: move mouse a bit, then wait 45 seconds) but I noticed no other interaction. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console, then ran top, but both these operations came at a significant delay. Other keyboard actions, such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> produced no effect (or nothing before I stopped waiting).

Comment: What do you mean by "my computer froze"? I'm curious, because if the computer is frozen, you can't use top.

Comment: What processor is in the host? Is it an 8-core CPU, or a 4-core with hyper-threading?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton, it became almost non-responsive. I could get the cursor to move at a great delay (read: move mouse a bit, then wait 45 seconds) but I noticed no other interaction. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a console, then ran top, but both these operations came at a significant delay.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, the processor is 'Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz'.  4 cores. Full description available at http://pastebin.com/Z4Fn5BR3

Comment: Latest version of VB? Guest updates applied? Hardware acceleration enabled and working properly? BIOS supports virtualization (it hasn't been turned off)? Not using it for a malware sandbox?

Comment: @ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ, VB 4.3.10_Ubuntu r93012. Guest additions installed. I haven't messed with the BIOS except to enable VT-x. I'm not sure if that answers your 'hardware acceleration' question. (If not, how can I check?) And no, I'm not sandboxing for malware or doing anything immoral.

Comment: It isn't possible for VirtualBox to assign more processors to a virtual machine then your physical machine actually support.  So I am going to guess you didn't read the data you received from `top` correctly so provide that data and we can explain it.

Comment: @Ramhound, I can't reproduce it now that the computer's not stuck. I killed the offending process. It would come as quite a surprise if I mistook the meaning of `400` in the first row under the `%CPU` column, though.

Comment: So you ran this command from within the host operating system or the guest operating system.  Just because you limited the virtual machine to only 3 cores does not mean that virtualbox itself wouldn't have the capability to use 100% utilization of the CPU itself.

Comment: @Ramhound, I ran `top` from the host. The host froze. I believed that the configuration above meant that the VM would use no more than 3 of the host processors.

Comment: @JellicleCat - You believe incorrectly.  You can run multiple virtual machines at once so that wouldn't be possible your way.

Comment: Hardware acceleration in addition to VT-x: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-video ; next time it happens, you may also benefit from iotop, htop, and vmstat. Though I wonder if the guest can use 3 CPU's while VirtualBox itself is on 1, swapping can also contribute: In top "O,p" then "enter" shows swap in use, iotop shows what's busy swapping, htop is nicer, and vmstat is quicker.

Comment: @ǝɲǝɲbρɯͽ, thanks. I've added an image of my Acceleration config. I don't believe I enabled 3D acceleration at all on the guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That allocation is the number of GUEST cpus not the number of HOST cpus that can be used. While they are often very similar, virtualbox tries to use as little CPU as possible, they are not the same. Virtualbox, and any other VM software, will need to use some of your host CPU to emulate the other devices. (such as the video card)

The fact that your mouse got 'sticky' would also imply that VB is using a lot of threads to keep these emulations in order. If it were only using four the kernel would still be giving your GUI a good share.

In line with that I would suggest you're using the wrong tool to limit the amount of CPU that virtualbox uses. You're not really interested in the guest using 3 or 4 cores you're more interested in your other tasks getting a fair share of the processor.

The Linux kernel feature I suggest you look into is called [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) which allows you to classify processes into groups and ensure that these groups only take the CPU that you allow. This way the kernel can be configured to give VirtualBox all 400% of the CPU if your GUI doesn't need it, but to give everything else absolute priority on (say) two of those CPUs when they have something to do.